# Multiply two numbers larger than 255

Tags: c, numbers

I need a problem, i use PIC simulator to import2 numbers by serial port. First I send byte, 5 for example, then send sent 2 and in the third step I sent char for example *, and the result is 5*2=10. Everything is fine till I send larger number more than 255. It says wrong entry, I know that I can send only 255 by byte. But how can I import larger number. What should be changed in the code to work for larger numbers. Some ideas???????  thanks a lot

```
//================= konfigure LCD display
    // port for data PORTB
    sbit LCD_RS at RB4_bit;
    sbit LCD_EN at RB5_bit;
    sbit LCD_D4 at RB0_bit;
    sbit LCD_D5 at RB1_bit;
    sbit LCD_D6 at RB2_bit;
    sbit LCD_D7 at RB3_bit;

    sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISB4_bit;
    sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISB5_bit;
    sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISB0_bit;
    sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISB1_bit;
    sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISB2_bit;
    sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISB3_bit;
    //=========================================================

    //===========variables
    char operation;
    int nbr1=0,nbr2=0,result=0,rest=0;
    char txt[16],br[7];
    //=========================================================

    //======== delete empty spaces
    void empty_spaces(char array[]){
     int j=0,i=0,n=0;
     n=strlen(array);
     while(i<n){
        if(array[i]==' '){
            j=i;
            while(j<n){
                 array[j]=array[j+1];
                 ++j;
            }
            --n;
        }else
             ++i;
     }
     if(n>15)
             n=15;
    array[n]='\0';
    }
    //=========================================================

    //========function back int from the imported char

    int back_char(char operation ){
        if(operation=='+')
             return 1;
        if(operation=='-')
             return 2;
        if(operation=='*')
             return 3;
        if(operation=='/')
             return 4;
        if(operation=='%')
             return 5;
        return 0;
    }
    //=========================================================

    //============= init lcd display and serial port
    void inicijalizacija(){
      PORTB = 0xFF;
      TRISB = 0x00;
      ANSEL  = 0x00;
      ANSELH = 0x00;
      C1ON_bit = 0;
      C2ON_bit = 0;
      UART1_Init(9600);
      Delay_ms(100);
      Lcd_Init();
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
    }
    //=========================================================

    void main(){
         inicijalizacija();
        //============= enter first number
        UART1_Write_Text("first num:");
        UART1_Write(10);
        UART1_Write(13);
           do{
           }while(!UART1_Data_Ready());
        nbr1=UART1_Read();
        IntToStr(nbr1,br);
        strcpy(txt,"Num1:");
        strcat(txt,br);
        empty_spaces(txt);
        Lcd_Out(1,1,txt);
        Delay_ms(1);


        //=============enter second number
        UART1_Write_Text("second num:");
        UART1_Write(10);
        UART1_Write(13);
           do{
           }while(!UART1_Data_Ready());
        nbr2=UART1_Read();
        IntToStr(nbr2,br);
        strcpy(txt,"Num2:");
        strcat(txt,br);
        empty_spaces(txt);
        Lcd_Out(1,10,txt);
        Delay_ms(1);
        //==============================================================

       //enter operation

        UART1_Write_Text("operation(+,-,/,*,%):");
        UART1_Write(10);
        UART1_Write(13);
           do{
           }while(!UART1_Data_Ready());
       operation=UART1_Read();
        strcpy(txt,"oper:");
        switch(back_char(operation)){
            case 0: strcat(txt," ");break;
            case 1:
                    strcat(txt,"+");
                    result=nbr1+nbr2;
                    break;
            case 2:
                    strcat(txt,"-");
                    result=nbr1-nbr2;
                    break;
            case 3:
                    strcat(txt,"*");
                    result=nbr1*nbr2;
                    if(nbr2!=result/nbr1)
                        operation=' ';
                    break;
            case 4:
                    strcat(txt,"/");
                    if(nbr2==0)
                        operation=' ';
                    else{
                        result=nbr1/nbr2;
                        rest=nbr1%nbr2;
                    }
                    break;
            case 5:
                    strcat(txt,"%");
                    if(nbr2==0)
                        operation=' ';
                    else
                        result=nbr1%nbr2;
                    break;
            }
        empty_spaces(txt);
        Lcd_Out(2,1,txt);
        Delay_ms(1);
        //==============================================================

        //============= Print result

        if(back_char(operation)!=0){
            IntToStr(result,br);
            strcpy(txt,"Rez:");
            strcat(txt,br);
            empty_spaces(txt);
            if(back_char(operation)!=4)
                Lcd_Out(2,7,txt);
            else{                      // Dokolku vrednosta od funkcijata vrati_znak(operacija) e 4
                IntToStr(rest,br);      // se raboti za delenje
                empty_spaces(br);
                strcat(txt,"~");
                strcat(txt,br);
                Lcd_Out(2,5,txt);
            }
        }else
            Lcd_Out(2,7,"error!");
        Delay_ms(1);
        //==============================================================
    }
```

Comment: Woa. That's a load of code to wade through...

Comment: i know but what you think about import to numbers larger than 255. is there some function in c or something else?

Comment: All that code still does not show us what "says wrong entry". We need to know that.

Comment: the code doesn't says but the serial port says because of the large number i sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that

```
(a + b) * c == (a * c) + (b * c)
```

to break your multiplication into smaller chunks, but you'll still have to deal with the fact that the final result may be larger than what will fit into whatever type you're using.

Comment: but when I send string for example (5*10)*6, is there function to convert string to int, and then calculate the statement? or not?

Comment: Sorry -- I don't know what functions might be available to you; I'm just suggesting a way to break up your problem to use smaller operands. If you want to do 265*3, you can do 255*3 and 10*3 and add the two results together yourself, being careful to deal with any overflow. It's always painful to try to work around limitations. Good luck.